# Android chatting app development

Tags: android

I want to make an Android app where there will be several clients and an admin.The app will be installed in client's device.Admin can be send message from ***computer*** to the clients and clients could be ***reply*** the message.
The admin could be also send notification to the all clients or to individual client.

Can anyone give me some suggestions that which technologies should i use to build such an app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a backend for your app with a database to store user informations , messages etc... I suggest you to use a non-relational database because access to db values it's more efficient for this uses-case.

To make it easy you could try **Firebase Cloud Messaging**.

Here the official site

[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) which provides you a bunch of products like notification, authentication,cloud storage, cloud messaging, Notification. You can easily integrate this in your app by just following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).